# Creating ctags extension for markdown

Tags: vim, markdown, ctags

I edit quite a few markdown files using Vim these days. One thing I'm missing is a map of the file like function list in C based on ctags. So I came up with the following .ctags file

```
--langdef=markdown
--langmap=markdown:.md
--regex-markdown=/^# ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/\1/
```

It runs OK but generates no valid tags for my .md file. With verbose mode turned on I get the following:

```
Considering option file /home/wenliang/.ctags: reading...
 Option: --langdef=markdown
 Option: --langmap=markdown:.md
 Setting markdown language map: .md
Option: --regex-markdown=/^# ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/\1/
Considering option file ./.ctags: not found
```

What's wrong with what I did?

Comment: Looks fine to me. What's your source Markdown document, and what gets created?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your definition looks OK.

What command did you use to generate your `tags` file? `$ ctags .` won't index anything but `$ ctags -R .` will.

FWIW, here is a slightly modified version of your definition that provides meaningful tag names and kind informations:

```
--langdef=markdown
--langmap=markdown:.md
--regex-markdown=/^#[ \t](.*$)/\1/h,heading,headings/
```

[image: :tselect /<CR>]

---

As an alternative, you might be interested in these cheaper, built-in, solutions…

- using the `define` option and `:dlist`:

  ```
  :setlocal define=^#\\s*
  :dli /<CR>
  ```
- using `:ilist` and no setup:

  ```
  :il /#<CR>
  ```

which both produce the same list, ready for you to type `:126<CR>`:

[image: :il /#<CR>]

See `:help :ilist`, `:help :dlist`, `:help 'define'`.

Comment: What colorscheme is that? I really like it.

Comment: @ldigas, thanks, it's called [Apprentice](https://github.com/romainl/Apprentice).